# how to get page to curl like in Apple Maps on iOS 6?

Tags: ios, dictionary, ios6, page-curl

How would I get my page to curl up as it does in the new apple maps?  I know how to make it curl up to see another page but I'm talking about the curl in the bottom right corner of the map.  Here is a pic if you want to see what I'm talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display this curly corner, simply use a PNG image (which contains the curly white part with its gradient and shadow + the gray background part of the supposed below view, the rest of the PNG being transparent -- *similar to [this one found via Google Image for example](http://www.zapmedia.co.uk/support_files/page_curl.png)*).

You can then use this image as the `backgroundImage` of a `UIButton` -- or as the `image` an `UIImageView` to which you can add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` -- and then add it as a subview of your frontmost view, in its bottom right corner. Then simply configure this button (or the `UIImageView`'s `UITapGestureRecognizer`) so it triggers the curl animation on tap.

Comment: The only problem with this is that the map curls up and the page curl stays in place -- hovering on the window. That I know of, you cannot add a graphic (button) to the map view such that it curls up with the mkmapview.  Am I wrong? (I would love to be wrong)